kWh Calculation, 208v 3 phase
I data logged a generator for a little over 5 days at the 1 minute interval, 7332 samples.
I am trying to calculate the total energy generated during this time. So I have L1,L2, and L3 Amps, kW, and Voltages.
How to I calculate the total energy? Do I add up the kW on each line? Should I total the Amps first?


You're almost done! There's a total kW column: Figure out how long you want to assume that power has been provided.

(I suggest you roll back to revision 1.)

@greybeard Are you suggesting to SUM the Total column? Then divide by the total hours or minutes?

I would add them all up then divide by 60. For every one hour you get 60 samples, and if you add 60 samples then divide by 60 you get average kWh for that one hour. Same thing for all of the samples, just add them all up and divide by 60.

SUM the Total column? yes. divide by the total hours or minutes? on the contrary: multiply! Energy is power times time as witnessed in the units: Ws (J); kWh.

Brian is right.
No need to go back to each line current.
Once you have total kW all you have to do is multiply by each time interval, that is constant and equal to 1 minute = 1/60 hour.
Power is Energy/time
watt = joule/second
Between 15:27 and 15:28 the total power holds on 10.05 kW
During that minute the enery is
10050 * 60 joules
factor:
1 joule * 1W*s/1J * 1kW/1000W * 1h/3600s
10050*60/(3600000) =
multiply each Total kW on right column by
1/60
